# Cocos2D for Android textures disappear

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

Some times textures disappear from sprites. I have a sprite that appears with white color and it should have a texture on it and a label that should have a text in it an it appears with black color. The labels are subclasses of sprite so this problem is related to Sprites. Could some one tell me what is the problem ? Did some one meet this bug to in Cococs2D on Android ? Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem when I was doing navigation from "outside" of cocos2d i.e. i relied on Android's native back button's callback to change scenes. Apparently this callback doesn't work on the same thread as cocos and causes this problem (maybe something with WeakReferences in the TextureCache). Hope it helps :)

Comment: When I go back I destroy the current scene and I recreate it again when I reenter

Comment: Sure, that's perfectly fine, but do you go back using the hardware "Back" button - the callback to which is in the Activity, or rather you use a Cocos2D button to do it?

Comment: I'v implementede a back button and I use the hardeware back button but same buttons I'v directed tu do the same thing. Any whay I solved this problem. It was from CCDirector.sharedDirector().end() methode witch when I destroy the scene. Eliminating this methode solved my problem. Thenks for help

Comment: I have just one more problem. If you can help me with this I apreciate :). First when I use setString for CCLabel it's texture become black. From what I'v read when setString is called a texture is recreated for that label in opengl (behind cocos2d). And second in same scene I have a sprite near this label that has a texture on it and when I call setString for label olso I call a methode to remove the sprite with it's texture and I recreate another sprite with other texture and put it back but the sprite appears white, without texture on it. Thenks for help again :)

Comment: This happends when I pres a button to do this has nothing to do with back button and back stack

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pvr? When I tried using pvr I was getting what sounds like the same issues. I switched to png and it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'm using just pngs for textures and in a scene I have , let say 3 objects (sprites), every time disappears my texture from background sprite and one or two textures from the other sprites, other times disappear textures from all sprites in that scene.

Comment: I'v seen that first time when I enter in my scene every think works perfect but when I go back and come in again textures disappear but not immediately and after few seconds or after I play with some objects in the scene